# onOpen "hide sheets" doesn't work for Viewers of a Google Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, permissions

I have a "hide sheets" function. I've tried using it as an onOpen function, and also with a On Open *trigger*.

It works fine if an Editor opens the GS.

But if a Viewer opens the GS, it doesn't work at all.
If it's an On Open *trigger*, I get an error email that "Authorization is required to perform that action."
If it's called as an onOpen *function*, it just doesn't work, but also doesn't generate any errors.

Is there a way to make this work for *Viewers*?

Comment: `onOpen` trigger should not perform sensitive actions, at most create a menu. Also, why did you expect a function that modifies spreadsheet structure to work for users who only have read-only access? If you *absolutely* necessary have to hide it from viewers, add them temporarily to editors list and remove once done. But a better flow would be to *show* additional sheets to users who have sufficient permissions, not the other way around

Answer (score 3):

Viewers can't execute scripts including those called by simple triggers like `onOpen`

One option among many others is to have one spreadsheet for editors and another for viewers then somehow send the changes made by the editors to spreadsheet shared with viewers.

Related

- [Google Spreadsheet - Show sheets depending on type of user](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22368964/1595451)
- [Getting all viewers of spreadsheet using App Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58322286/1595451)

Answer (score 2):

### Consideration

`onOpen` trigger should not perform sensitive actions, at most create a menu.

A simple trigger won't be able to run under this low privileged scope (viewer-only).

A better flow would be to show additional sheets to users who have sufficient permissions, not the other way around.

### Reference

[Triggers Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions)

Comment: They do not run if a file is opened in read-only (view or comment) mode.